# Can "find my phone" still track my Samsung Galaxy S4 after factory reset?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, factory-reset, lost-phone, gps-tracking

Just lost my Samsung Galaxy S4 this weekend. If the thief has removed the SIM card and reset to factory mode, does the "find my phone" app still work or does it also get removed?

Been trying to track it but nothing happens. Can I find it if the thief has put his information into the find my phone app that comes with the device?

Answer (score 1):

No, the app will be removed along with all other apps and user data. If you root the phone, it's possible to install a tracker as a system app, such that it will only be removed if the thief flashes a new ROM, but any app you install from Google Play or another app marketplace won't be able to do that.